# VBA, problems opening .xlsm file on Share Point with Workbooks.Open method

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

**Background:**
As part of version control subroutine in my VBA macro, I'm opening a .xlsm file stored in a folder on our corporate Share Point and saving it on a local hard drive.
The file gets opened by Workbooks.Open method, i.e.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://<mySharePointFolderPath> & "/file1.xlsm"
```

When I rolled this out initially, it worked fine for everyone in the team (myself including), apart from one user. At first I thought it was that user's own network issue (they worked from home that day), but when they tried this in the office a few days later, the macro failed again on the above line. The error message says:

*"Run-time error '1004':Excel cannot access the file. There are several possible reasons: -The file name or path does not exist.-The file is being used by another program."*

None of these applies in our case though. 
So I started testing this and somehow managed to cause it to fail for me as well. I can't remember exactly what was it I did, but it was either when I had the file1.xlsm open in Excel the moment I tried to open it again from SP, or when I temporarily removed the file from SP but tried to open it with the macro anyway. Most importantly though, now it fails for me every time I try while it continues to work fine for everyone else (apart from that other user).

**Problem:**
Unable to open the file from Share Point using:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://<mySharePointFolderPath> & "/file1.xlsm"
```

**Other factors:**
The affected user and I are both able to:

1. go to SP folder (via internet browser), download file1.xlsm and open it.
2. open other .xlsm files in that folder using the above method.
3. open the .xlsm file in question with Workbooks.Open after it has been renamed (to i.e. file2.xlsm)
4. open file1.xlsm after modifying the above line to: `Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\<mySharePointFolder> & "\file1.xlsm"`
   but it takes much, much longer to resolve AND still triggers the error 1004 message.

However

5. opening the file from Excel/File/Open menu (i.e.
   File/Open/SharePoint Sites, etc.) gives both of us the following error
   message:

   *"No items to show - We can't open this workbook. It's set to show only certain named items, but they aren't in the workbook. You might
   want to contact the author for more information."*

   While the workbook does have some named ranges which are hidden and
   other named ranges that are visible but refer to xlVeryHidden
   worksheets, they all are in the workbook, I am absolutely sure about
   that. Plus, if this was the cause of the issue, then it should not
   work for other users of after simply renaming the file.

So, it behaves almost as if Excel somehow *remembered* that it once failed trying to open file1.xlsm and is failing every attempt since (no, it's not listed under disabled add-ins).

Comment: There may be a conflict with other users having the file open or checked out.  Try opening read only with... Workbooks.Open Filename:=filepath, ReadOnly:=True

Comment: Thanks, @JohnnyD I tried that but it makes no difference. I wanted to use Workbooks.CanCheckOut test in my code to exactly prevent multiple users accessing the file at the same time, but for some reason it always returns False for every file i test this on.

Comment: For future reference, I ended up mapping SharePoint as drive on local machine, then copying the file over. This seems to be working fine for all users regardless of their location.

Comment: @JK2017.....can you give me a little more info about mapping SharePoint as a drive on a local machine?  Any code you would be willing to share would be greatly appreciated.  thanks.....

Comment: @Shaves - I see I should have been more specific back there, mapping a SharePoint folder was what I did. If that's what you are looking for, then one way to do it is:
Create a Windows Script Host object then use its MapNetworkDrive method, so:
Set objNetwrk = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
objNetwrk.MapNetworkDrive <enter your drive letter here> & ":", <enter your SP URL here> This is the minimum code needed, expand it as required. From experience, the SP site needs to be in under Trusted Sites.

Comment: @JK2017.....Thanks for the info.  We got some additional information yesterday and it looks like this might not be an issue for us until 5 years down the road.  We were originally that it was going to happen in the near future.  Thanks for the help....